# Can user add/change properties of the "request" object (and cause a security vulnerability)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, middleware

I'm very new to Node.js, and have written some code like

request.validToken = true;

Once I have confirmed that the token in a request is valid.

And I am then short cutting the check if validToken is already true. But what I wonder is, could the request be edited by an attacker to make this field exist on the original request, and therefore allowing them to bypass security checks?

If so, what would be the best practice?

Comment: The outside world cannot modify direct properties on the request object. In express things like request.query (url query params), and request.body will have user data.

Comment: If possible, that would have to be one of the biggest blunders .. :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way for a client to access the `request` object in node.

The only chance would be if you were blinding setting properties on the `request` object using data from the client, like:

```
Object.keys(request.body).forEach(function(k) {
  request[k] = request.body[k];
});
```

Only then could someone POST a form body that would overwrite/set properties on `request`.